# Is Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.IAsyncCollector<T> thread-safe?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

The interface's summary describes itself as 'an insert-only collection' but i can't seem to find any information regarding it's thread safeness.

Edit:

This interface is implemented by many classes inside the SDK with 'MessageSenderAsyncCollector' being the one i was curious about. The only thing it does as pointed by @rasmusgude is to call a static method from another class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is thread safe:

- [PartitionCollector](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/1fffabf0aeaea9e1ef49cd9abb888ef824d2e34a/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/EventHubs/EventHubAsyncCollector.cs) (which implements IAsyncCollector) adds `EventData` to a `List` inside a `lock`
- [MessageSenderAsyncCollector](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/f129fabd26ef5ea100753155681d321e5703a900/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus/Bindings/MessageSenderAsyncCollector.cs) (which implements IAsyncCollector) calls `ServiceBusEntity:SendAndCreateEntityIfNotExistsAsync` which by itself is thread safe

Comment: I ran the code again and the concrete class is indeed 'MessageSenderAsyncCollector' so it should be fine.